# Frontend image uploading from frontend cant handle hebrew names

Tags: front-end, language, uploads, file-manager

i'm using the [insert_attachment code](http://goldenapplesdesign.com/2010/07/03/front-end-file-uploads-in-wordpress/) in my functions.php :

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
}
```

and build a nice form in a static page :

```
 <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <p><label for="first_name">שם</label>
              <input type="text" id="first_name" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="first_name" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="last_name">משפחה</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="last_name" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="tatto_artist">מקעקע</label>
            <input type="text" id="tatto_artist" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="tatto_artist" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="tatto_age">גיל הקעקוע</label>
            <input type="text" id="tatto_age" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="tatto_age" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="tatto_price">מחיר</label>
            <input type="text" id="tatto_price" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="tatto_price" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="tatto_name">שם הקעקוע</label>
            <input type="text" id="tatto_name" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="tatto_name" />
          </p>
          <p><label for="post_tags" style="float: right;width: 95px;line-height: 1; height: 50px;">ספר על הקעקוע</label>
            <textarea id="post_tags" tabindex="3" name="post_tags" cols="30" rows="2" name="post_tags"></textarea>
          </p>
          <p class="upload"><label for="thumbnail">העלה תמונה : </label>
            <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"/>
          </p>

          <p><input type="submit" value="שלח" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
          <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
        </form>
```

as you can see, the form is in hebrew. when i'm trying to upload attachment :

```
if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
    echo ($attach_id);
  }
}
```

my problems begin...

the photos are loaded but if their names is in hebrew - it saves them in other names and cant find them.

for example:
name of file from my pc: סקיצה (1).jpg
the name after i uploaded it, in the wp uploads folder : ׳¡׳§׳™׳¦׳”-1.jpg

does anyone have any ideas how to handle this situation?